# Java null pointer exception while using array of objects

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am getting a null pointer when I run this piece of code. Its self-explanatory , two classes are used to model a Book and a Library.

I would appreciate it if someone can tell me where I am going wrong.

```
public class Library {


    private String address;
    private final static String workinghours = "9AM to 5PM";
    private Book[] bookcollection = new Book[6];
    private static int numberofbooks = 0;

    public Library(String libraryaddress) {
        address = libraryaddress;
    }

    public static void printOpeningHours() {
        System.out.println(workinghours);
    }

    public void addBook(Book newaddition) {
        bookcollection[numberofbooks] = newaddition;
        numberofbooks++;
    }

    public void printAddress() {
        System.out.println(address);
    }

    public void borrowBook(String bookname) {
        for (int i = 0; i < bookcollection.length; i++) {

            if (bookcollection[i].getTitle().equals(bookname)&&(!(bookcollection[i].isBorrowed()))) 
            {
                bookcollection[i].borrowed();
                break;
            }

        }

    }

    public void returnBook(String bookname) {
        for (int i = 0; i < bookcollection.length; i++) {

            if (bookcollection[i].getTitle().equals(bookname)) {
                bookcollection[i].returned();
                break;
            }

        }

    }

    public void printAvailableBooks() {
        for (int i = 0; i < bookcollection.length; i++) {

            if (!(bookcollection[i].isBorrowed())) {
                System.out.println(bookcollection[i].getTitle());
            }

        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create two libraries
        Library firstLibrary = new Library("10 Main St.");
        Library secondLibrary = new Library("228 Liberty St.");

        // Add four books to the first library
        firstLibrary.addBook(new Book("The Da Vinci Code"));
        firstLibrary.addBook(new Book("Le Petit Prince"));
        firstLibrary.addBook(new Book("A Tale of Two Cities"));
        firstLibrary.addBook(new Book("The Lord of the Rings"));

        // Print opening hours and the addresses
        System.out.println("Library hours:");
        printOpeningHours();
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Library addresses:");
        firstLibrary.printAddress();
        secondLibrary.printAddress();
        System.out.println();

        // Try to borrow The Lords of the Rings from both libraries
    /*  System.out.println("Borrowing The Lord of the Rings:");
        firstLibrary.borrowBook("The Lord of the Rings");
        firstLibrary.borrowBook("The Lord of the Rings");
        secondLibrary.borrowBook("The Lord of the Rings");
        System.out.println();*/

        // Print the titles of all available books from both libraries
        System.out.println("Books available in the first library:");
        firstLibrary.printAvailableBooks();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Books available in the second library:");
        secondLibrary.printAvailableBooks();
        System.out.println();

        // Return The Lords of the Rings to the first library
        System.out.println("Returning The Lord of the Rings:");
        firstLibrary.returnBook("The Lord of the Rings");
        System.out.println();

        // Print the titles of available from the first library
        System.out.println("Books available in the first library:");
        firstLibrary.printAvailableBooks();
    }
}
```

```
//Library uses objects of class book as members  

public class Book {

    String title;
    boolean borrowed;

    // Creates a new Book
    public Book(String bookTitle) {

        title = bookTitle;
        borrowed = false ;
    }

    // Marks the book as rented
    public void borrowed() {

        borrowed = true;
    }

    // Marks the book as not rented
    public void returned() {

        borrowed = false;
    }

    // Returns true if the book is rented, false otherwise
    public boolean isBorrowed() {

        return ((borrowed) ? true : false);

    }

    // Returns the title of the book
    public String getTitle() {

        return title;
    }

    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        // Small test of the Book class
        Book example = new Book("The Da Vinci Code");
        System.out.println("Title (should be The Da Vinci Code): "
                + example.getTitle());
        System.out.println("Borrowed? (should be false): "
                + example.isBorrowed());
        example.borrowed();
        System.out.println("Borrowed? (should be true): "
                + example.isBorrowed());
        example.returned();
        System.out.println("Borrowed? (should be false): "
                + example.isBorrowed());
    }
}
```

Comment: Two comments: Where do you get the NPE? and, Please try to accept some of the answers to your previous questions.

Comment: you can look at your stack and which line throw the exception.

Comment: I like the parking lot analogy.  Think of an array of objects like a parking lot.  You must fill it with cars (objects) before you can try to drive one of the cars (use one of the objects).  And I too second the comment above that you should go back through your questions and accept some answers.  This will encourage others to help you in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing all loops that look like

```
for (int i = 0; i < bookcollection.length; i++) {
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberofbooks; i++) {
```

As it stands now, you will try to do `bookcollection[i].getTitle()` on an entry in the books-array that has not yet been assigned a value (that is, still contains null).

Comment: thanks , i realized my mistake. I guess avoiding null pointer exceptions requires good programming. i now have used numberofbooks in the for loop and also have an if clause when numberofbooks==0 -> "no book in catalog".

Comment: Yes, I saw that, that's why I didn't bother to write a long and explaining answer :-)

Answer (score 3):

When you create an array of books with `private Book[] bookcollection = new Book[6];`, each `Book` in the array is initially `null`.  So, when you loop through the array without checking for `null`, you will get a `NullPointerException`.  One place this will happen is in `printAvailableBooks()`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < bookcollection.length; i++) {
    if (!(bookcollection[i].isBorrowed())) { // NPE if bookcollection[i] is null!
        ....
```

To fix this, loop over `numberofbooks`, which should match the number of non-`null` books.

Answer (score 0):

One more point that I believe has to be noted is that

> numberofbooks

should not be a static variable.
This is because, it will be common to firstLibrary and secondLibrary.

Say you have added 4 books in firstLibrary and then you add a book in secondLibrary, it is stored in the 5th position of the array. Thereby 1st four indices of secondLibrary contains a null and 5th index contains a book.

Another problem that can arise due to this is ArrayIndexOutofBoundException.

Comment: yes I understood that, I changed it while revising the code. Good catch nonetheless.